# How to create a reference to an array created dynamically using new operator in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int accept(int &,int );//int accept(int*,int)
int main()
{
    int n=3;
    //int arr[3]={0,1,2};
    int *marks=new int[n]; //creating an array dynamically
    //int (&ref_arr)[3]=arr;// I know how to create a reference to statically created array;
    int* &ref_marks=marks;//creating reference for array;
    accept(ref_marks,n);
    return 0;
}

int accept(int &marks,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>marks[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could  you please help me out with creating reference to an array which is on heap area.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers and vice versa.

Comment: `marks` accepts a reference to a single integer, so `cin>>marks[i];` is headed in the wrong direction. You need something more along the lines of `int accept(int * marks,int n)`

Comment: You should use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
using int3 = int[3];
int3& ref = reinterpret_cast<int3&>(*marks);
```

However it would be better practice to just use `std::array` or `std::vector`.